# create new column containing a substring of an existing column in data using bash

Tags: string, bash, gzip, large-data, text-extraction

I have a large tsv.gz file (40GB) for which I want to extract a string from an existing variable `col3`, store it in a new variable `New_var` (placed at the beginning) and save everything the new file.
an example of the data "old_file.tsv.gz"

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
1  positive  12:1234A  100
2  negative  10:9638B  110
3  positive  5:0987A  100
4  positive  8:5678A  170
```

Desired data "new_file.tsv.gz"

```
New_var  col1  col2  col3  col4
12  1  positive  12:1234A  100
10  2  negative  10:9638B  110
5  3  positive  5:0987A  100
8  4  positive  8:5678A  170
```

I am new in bash so I have tried multiple things but I get stuck, I have tried

```
zcat old_file.tsv.gz | awk '{print New_var=$3,$0 }' | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]:/{print $0 | (gzip -c > new_file.tsv.gz) }'
```

I think I have multiple problems. `{print New_var=$3,$0 }` do create a duplicate of `col3` but doesn't rename it. Then when I add the last part of the code `awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]:/{print $0 | (gzip -c > new_file.tsv.gz) }'`...well nothing comes up (I tried to look if I forget a parenthesis but cannot find the problem).
Also I am not sure if this way is the best way to do it.
Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: There is no question in your question. (Hint: questions end with a question mark.) Also, what have you tried? Where did you run into a problem?

Comment: Sorry I have tried so many things that I am unsure that it is difficult to say where I am at. I updated my post, I hope it can help. My question is going back to "how to make this thing happen?"

Comment: Why do you have a backtick before `$1` ? Why is your `gzip` inside your awk script?

Comment: @jhnc the backtick was a mistake and is corrected. Thanks for catching it! The gzip comes from solution I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374943/split-a-large-gz-file-into-smaller-ones-filtering-and-distributing-content and used previously.

Comment: Still not a single question mark in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an AWK script in a separate file (for readability), say `1.awk`:

```
{ if (NR > 1) { 
    # all data lines 
    split($3, a, ":");  
    print a[1], $1, $3, $3, $4; 
  } else {
    # header line
    print "new_var", $1, $2, $3, $4;
  } 
}
```

Now process the input (say `1.csv.gz`) with the AWK file:

```sh
zcat 1.csv.gz | awk -f 1.awk | gzip -c > 1_new.csv.gz
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much! I didn't know about the split function.

Comment: Yes, `split` is quite useful if you want to process a field. By the way there a lot of [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) available in AWK.

Comment: Thanks that is really useful! I am using R but very little of bash. Question: I realize that with this code, the data is not parsed correctly. I think it is because I have to use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` somewhere but can't figure out where. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You can use the `-v` flag of AWK to set variables in startup (even before the BEGIN block). For example, to set the input/output field separators, you can do: `awk -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' -f 1.awk ...`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use one tab (`\t`) and `:` as input field separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[\t:]"; OFS="\t" }
     NR==1 { $1="New_var" OFS $1 }
     NR>1  { $0=$3 OFS $0 }
     { print }'
```

As one line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="[\t:]"; OFS="\t" } NR==1{ $1="New_var" OFS $1 } NR>1{ $0=$3 OFS $0 } { print }'
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Thank for the help and for the link! It works well! Unfortunately I cannot use it for my larger data because I have the character ":" in other column that I don't want to be parsed.